# translating basel problem written in c++ into C program

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet but as I'm a beginner, I don't understand c++.
I think I can understand it if I can see it in C code. Would it be possible to translate this to C?
i understand the logic of for loop but I don't know <<

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        int nTerm = 0;
        cout << "Number of terms to use: " << endl;
        cin >> nTerm;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1; i<=nTerm; i++){
            sum += 1 / pow(i, 2);
        }
        cout << "Sum of first " << nTerm << " terms of the Basel problem is: " << sum << endl;
        cout << "This leads to an approximation of pi as: " << sqrt(6 * sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "Translate to C"? This is just fancy C code. There's nothing exotic going on here at all other than using `cout` to print things.

Comment: Tip: Step through in a debugger to become enlightened.

Comment: The `cout <<` here is what you would do with `printf` in C.

Comment: Prefer to use `i * i` instead of `pow(i,2)`.  The `pow` function is for floating point (your integers will be converted to and from floating point which may introduce inaccuracies).  The multiplication is simpler, faster and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The only translation you need here between C and C++ are the lines with `cout`, just replace them with a `printf("")`, for example
cout << "Number of terms to use: " << endl;

will be translated as

```
printf(""Number of terms to use: \n")
```

and

```
cin >> nTerm;
```

will be translated as

```
scanf("%d", &nTerm)
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &nTerm)` would invoke undefined behavior. `nTerm` is an `int`, not a char array

Comment: @UnholySheep you're right, I was just trying to write an arbitrary example of cin, cout comparison with printf and scanf, I did not care for the real data types, sorry about that, and good captcha bud

Comment: thank you but I switched that but the code isn't executing like it did for c++ hmm maybe I'm doing it wrong. would you mind checking it on your side?

Comment: @DiegoSerranoGómez this is a case where you have to be very careful. `scanf` will take hilariously wrong arguments, grin, and then completely <expletive deleted> up at runtime, often with no warnings whatsoever. A friendly compiler will verify the format arguments  against the parameters given and issue a warning, but to my knowledge only a few of the major compilers are that kind. I've fixed the mistake because it's not the sort of thing we should leave lying around. Some kid could find it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for that, you are totally right to fix the code. And LoL I know what you mean about strange outputs, makes you feel like you're hacking the Matrix haha